# Accessing a service inside an event subscriber

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, lifecycle

I have an event subscriber with Doctrine events. Inside that, I am trying to call a service I have registered. I've called it already from in a controller and it works there, but when I try to call it in my event subscriber I get an error:

```
Attempted to call method "get" on class "Path\To\My\Class".
Did you mean to call "getSubscribedEvents"?
```

The code looks like this:

```
$embedcode_service = $this->get('myproject.mynamespace.myfield.update');
$embedcode_service->refreshMyField($document);
```

Why can't I access my service inside this event subscriber? How can I get access to it?

Comment: Does your event subscriber even have a get method?  I suspect not since it is not a controller.  Inject your service into the subscriber's construct method.  Look at the Services section in the documentation.

Comment: I didn't know "inject" was the word I was looking for. I've been sifting through too much documentation to actually see any of it, it seems. If you turn this into an answer and link the relevant section of the documentation I'll accept it.

Comment: Too lazy but thanks anyways.  Someone else can post a proper answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Cerad already answered I'm just going to elaborate:

Inject your service in your subscriber:

```
services:
    ...
    my.subscriber:
            class: Acme\SearchBundle\EventListener\SearchIndexerSubscriber
            # Service you want to inject
            arguments: [ @service_i_want_to_inject.custom ]
            tags:
                - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
   ...
```

In the php code for your subscriber, assign the injected service to a class variable to be able to access it later on:

```
...
class SearchIndexerSubscriber implements EventSubscriber {

private $myservice;

public function __construct($myservice) {
    $this->myservice = $myservice;
}
...
```

Access the service methods through the class variable from any method within the subscriber:

```
$this->myservice->refreshMyField($document);
```

[Listeners/subscribers in Symfony2](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html)

[Services in Symfony2](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html)

Happy new year.